# Remover espaço entre menu e conteudo

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Olá estou com um pequeno problema... 
Digamos que entre o menu e os conteudos das páginas estão com esse buraco enorme...

[image: area verde]

E gostaria muito de remover ela... o pior que não tem nada no codigo para aumentar esse espaço ... ele apenas tá ali.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Altere o page-builder no seu css, coloque o padding 0

```
.page-builder{
    padding: 0;
}
```

Na imagem que você postou você pode ver que o padding top esta com 80px

Comment: Era exatamente isso Wictor, negocio bem simples e eu me matando... aprendendo sempre vlw msm !